# error in running java file

Tags: java, tomcat, error-handling

I am making a webapp using tomcat but its having problems in running in windows...there is a java file(thread.java) which runs another java file(emaildownload.java) so first I need to get to the directory in which class file is stored ...I am using

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
```

for getting class path...and then I am running file by:

```
thread foo=new thread();
foo.runProcess("java mainclasses.emaildownload "+credentials[0]+" "+credentials[1]+" "+credentials[2]+" "+credentials[3]+" ");
```

file structure:
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\Mazil3.0\WEB-INF\classes\mainclasses\emaildownload.class
and mainclasses is package...
but I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/UIDFolder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.UIDFolder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I don't understand why the error is coming?

Comment: Post your code and error in more details, to clearly identify the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Please include mail.jar in your classpath if you are using java.mail.UIDFolder class.

Comment: The error is caused because the mainclasses.emaildownload class (or a class directly or indirectly referenced by that class) references the javax.mail.UIDFolder class and the javax.mail.UIDFolder class is not in the classpath.  it appears that you are missing a jar.

Comment: I have included jar file but same error persists..

Answer (score 0):

Interface `UIDFolder` belongs to javax.mail package since it is saying NoClassDefFoundError so you might not be having the javamail api in your classpath .Get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4)